# How to auto update channel name using Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to understand how to *automatically* update a specific voice channels name in Discord. Looking through the API and around the site, I have found this:

```
@client.command()
async def emoivb(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel, new_name):
    await channel.edit(name=new_name)
```

However, I need it not as a command.

Example: Each time a person sends a specific message, the channel will increment its integer name by +1

Comment: Have you checked the events? For example the [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a json file to store the number of messages with name message and use the following code

```py
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
   channel_id="channel which is to be edited"
   channel=await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
   with open('message.json',"r") as f:
    messages=json.load(f)
   try:  
    x=messages[str(message.guild.id)]
    x=x+1
    messages[str(message.guild.id)]=x
    with open('message.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(messages,f,indent=4) 
    
    await channel.edit(name=str(x))  
   except:
      messages[str(message.guild.id)]=1
      with open('message.json',"w") as f:
        json.dump(messages,f,indent=4) 
      await channel.edit(name=str(1))
```